# How do I use application/xml as compared to text/xml?

Tags: java, xml, jersey

In the web service I've been working on, I've been displaying text to the screen through methods like so in HTML:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHtmlHello() 
{
/**Do some stuff
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello World" + "</h1></body></html>";
}
```

which displays to the screen quite nicely.  In order to fit the project description of the project I'm working on, I've been working on moving toward an XML output by building a document, transforming it to a string, and returning the string.  Using @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) shows the XML tree like I would expect.

My question comes here: I need to be able to pass this XML data on using what the project description calls a Response Content-Type Header of application/xml;charset=UTF-8.  So what would I need to do to accomodate using @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) instead of @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)?

Comment: Well, my partner on this project went ahead and changed "TEXT_XML" to "APPLICATION_XML" and it outputs fine.  So from what I can tell, both are handled the same way when called in a web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`application/xml` is generally the preferred mime type.  For `text/xml` it appears the encoding will generally be treated as `us ascii` regardless of what is specified in the XML document header (unless otherwise specified in the HTTP headers).

For More Information:

- http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/489
- http://www.imc.org/ietf-xml-mime/mail-archive/msg00496.html

Comment: not anymore - see rfc7303 section 4.1: "Compared to [RFC2376] or [RFC3023], this specification alters the handling of character encoding of text/xml and text/xml-external-parsed-entity, treating them no differently from the respective application/ types."

Answer (score 5):

Use application/xml for documents meant primarily to be processed by programs. Use text/xml for documents which are also meant for human reading for purposes other than debugging. I believe this is covered in RFC 2046.

Comment: RFC 2376 says to use text/xml for handling as plain text by default, also referencing RFC 2046 character encoding as mentioned by @brian-clozel